# How to evaluate expression before typesetting?

Tags: biblatex

This code:

```
\newcommand{\nosection}[1]{%
  \refstepcounter{section}%
  \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\numberline{\thesection}\fullcite{#1}%
  \markright{#1}}}
```

prints '\fullcite #1' where #1 is 1's value instead of the citation using 1 as a key. I would like to print 1's citation

Comment: Why do you need that (it isn't possible in general) ? isn't the cite looked up correctly when the contents are read back. Oh you probably don't want to affect the numbering, there are other ways to protect that.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Can you be more specific on your problem? I don't think that writing `\markright` in the `.toc` file is meaningful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because of the timing of the processing of the table of contents, citations there will not be processed unless cited elsewhere in the document.  An unrecognised citation is just replaced by its key in `biblatex`.  The way to make sure that your item is cited is to add a `\nocite` command outside the table of contents, then you can call `\fullcite` in the table of contents.

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{biblatex}

\newcommand{\nosection}[1]{%
  \refstepcounter{section}%
  \nocite{#1}%
  \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\numberline{\thesection}\fullcite{#1}}%
  \markright{#1}}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
  @Article{myart,
  author = {Author, A. N.},
  title = {Title},
  journal = {J.},
  year = 2006,
  volume = 10,
  pages = {21--27}
  }
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\nosection{myart}

\end{document}
```